# CardView border does not change

Tags: android, border, android-cardview

In my drawable folder

cardeviewborder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="20dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

In layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/cardviewborder"
        >



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listitemtaskname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="Hi" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listitemdatedetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:text="By" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

CardView border does not change.What am i doing wrong and i want the cardview to elevate above the relativelayout but that also does not happen even after adding elevation attribute.Please help
I want my carview to look something like this with border
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlppN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listitemtaskname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Hi" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listitemdatedetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            tools:text="By" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Check by removing the Relative layout, cardview will elevate.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `app:cardBackgroundColor` to change the backgroud of the `CardView` without affecting the elevation of the `CardView`.

You will lose the elevation of the CardView if you use this property: `android:background`

Comment: I want to chnage the border of the cardview and elevate it from RelativeLayout. Right now it seems there is no cardview as both cardview and relativelayout appears as same

Comment: Yes. You will lose the elevation if you use this property: `android:background`